# problemas con socket.io

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, socket.io, ejs

estoy haciendo un chat con logueo y registro en nodejs, el problema es al presionar el boton de enviar socket.emit tendria que mandar mandar el mensaje pero no sucede nada, no salta ningun error ni nada

codigo del servidor

```
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const io = socketIO(server);
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id);

    io.on('chat:mensaje', function (data) {
          io.sockets.emit('chat:mensaje', data)
    })
})
```

codigo del cliente

```
const socket = io();
output = document.getElementById('mensajes');
button = document.getElementById('boton');
input = document.getElementById('chat');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    socket.emit('chat:mensaje', {
        mensaje: input.value
    });
});

socket.on('chat:mensaje', (data)=>{
    output.innerHTML += '<div>'+ data.mensaje +'</div>';
})
```

Comment: Pusiste el código JS después del HTML? Se está ejecutando después de que se haya cargado el HTML? Qué pasa si agrega `console.log()` dentro del `addEventListener('click')`?

Comment: En el servidor cambia esta linea: `io.on('chat:mensaje' ...` por esto: `socket.on('chat:mensaje'...`. Comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: listo tenia que cambiar eso que me dijiste ahora funciona perfecto muchas gracias

Comment: De igual forma, toma en cuenta la respuesta aportada por @PabloLozano, es buena práctica colocar explícitamente (bien sea hardcoded o dinámicamente) la `url` del servidor `websocket` al que te estás conectando. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código del cliente no parece que hayas indicado a dónde tiene que enviar los mensajes, lo normal es usar algo como

```
const socket = io('http://localhost');
```

Sin eso, no vas a poder enviar nada.

Comment: Si no pasa un argumento a `io()`, toma el `url` de `window.location`, lo cual estaría bien si esa `url` es la misma en la que está el servidor. ;)